# Framework7 is not inserting loaded content from external links in the DOM

Tags: html-framework-7

This is my code:

```
<div class="page-content">
      <div class="block">
                <p>HomePage content goes here</p>
                <p><a href="/web/" >Get the page</a></p>
      </div>
</div>
```

And this is my routes:

```
routes: [
                {
                    name: 'Web',
                    path: '/web/',
                    url: 'http://website.com'
                },
]
```

When i click on the link, the request for `website.com` is successfully made, but the content of it is not inserted in the DOM.

What i want is to click that link and load that page inside the application like it's a normal local page of the application. i don't know if that's how it work or i didn't fully understand it.

Comment: Hi, do you need load API content or just a view page?... If its api you need to use `async(routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
      if (somthing...) {
        // code
      } else {
        // code
      }
    }` ...or IFREAM for view in page..... or normal extirnal link open by browser

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad i want to display the content of that external link inside the application, meaning i don't want to open the link in a new window. i want it to appear inside like it's a part of the application. i tried to use api with  `async ` but i get the same result, when i check `Network` in `inspect element` the request to the external has been made when i click the link, but the returned content of that request is not inserted in the page, the page stays unchanged

Comment: I think you cant got a content from website direct without using cronjob or js function...but sure you will got access origin issue...but you can open this page in your app by using "Cordova webview"....also you can try this `window.open('https://yoursite.com', '_self ', 'location=yes');` in a click event nested of using routes ...

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad ok thanks

Comment: Welcome mate....

Comment: Note: also you have an idea if you need a content....you can build a function in server thats trigger a CRUL for needed page and return content to your async function ...this will resolve your issue sure too....

Comment: @AneesHikmatAbuHmiad i fixed it with `template`, like this : ` template: <div class="page-content"><div class="block"><iframe src="http://example.com" style="height:100%;width:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe></div></div>`

Comment: Nice man, This is my first suggestion..by using FREAM :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185506/discussion-between-ler-and-anees-hikmat-abu-hmiad).